# Is accessing function parameters without knowing names possible

Tags: c++, linux, function

I wonder if it is possible to access the parameter list of a member function without knowing the names of all the parameters (but know every detail of types of all params). See the code below:

```
struct TypeA
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

class TypeB
{
public:
    string mSth;
    char*  mPtr;
};

class SomeClass
{
    public:
        inline void SomeFunc(struct TypeA, TypeB&)
        {
            // how to access the parameters here??
            // if no parameter names are given??
        }
};
```

Why I want to do this is because my code is generated by some tool, and each time this tool generates it gives different names to the paramter list of `SomeClass::SomeFunc`.

For example, this time it is `inline void SomeFunc(struct TypeA param1, TypeB& param2)` while next it might be `inline void SomeFunc(struct TypeA param3, TypeB& param4)`.

And I don't want to rewrite the function body only because the parameters name are changed.

Comment: `struct TypeA, TypeB&` both need a name if you want to use them in the function and it shouldn't compile without them.  A function prototype doesn't need to name the parameters but the definition does.

Comment: @NathanOliver No, you can have unnamed parameters in the definition, you just cannot access them.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Do you have a standard citation for that? I've seen unnamed parameters in function definitions a lot. It's one way to avoid "unused variable" warnings, and I've never seen a compiler that complains about it in any way.

Comment: @BaummitAugen:  Sorry for the incorrect information.  I could have sworn I had a compiler fail with unnamed parameters but I tired now and it works.  Maybe it was the compiler I was using.

Comment: @NathanOliver one instance where you use unnamed parameters is "tag dispatching" in generic programming, where you overload a function based on different "tags", then another function calls the right overload based on what tag was passed as a parameter, but doesn't effectively manipulate the tag. See e.g. `std::forward_iterator_tag` and related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `SomeFunc` is not overloaded you can access the types in a limited way, and you know the name of the function.  You can generate a bundle of types that contains the list of the types of the parameters.

You cannot, however, access the parameters themselves.

Probably the easiest way to solve your problem is to forward the function to another function that you write that has stable parameter names.  Then only the "wrapping" function need be rewritten, the wrapped one does not.

```
    inline void SomeFunc(struct TypeA random_name_77, TypeB& random_name_82)
    {
      auto impl=[this](struct TypeA&& p1, TybeB& p2){
        // your code goes here
      };
      impl(
        std::forward<decltype(random_name_77)>(random_name_77),
        std::forward<decltype(random_name_77)>(randon_name_82)
      );
    }
```

Now only the tail part -- the part that calls `impl` -- need be changed when the parameter names generated by the tool change.  The new parameter names, inside `impl`, are whatever you choose.

The `&&` and `std::forward<decltype(var)>(var)` are ways to enable perfect forwarding and avoid spurious copies.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot access unnamed parameters in your function.

The solution for your problem is to either improve your bad tool or ditch it.